# TermDocumentMatrix in R does not function

Tags: r, twitter, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

I have a corpus look like this:
My corpus, myCorpus1 has been included 33704 tweets. You can see it below of code. But when I create midterm matrix, which is TermDocument Matrix, there are only 3732 documents. My question is how the TermDocumentMatrix function? Am I missing anything? Or, this function does not treat each tweet as a document, but instead it has its own way of parsing documents?I am wondering why there are very few terms. I guess there should be more than 10902 in a 33704-tweet text

```
tweet_text2<-tweets2$text
myCleanedText <- sapply(tweet_text2,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))
as.vector(myCleanedText)
df<-data.frame(myCleanedText)
myCorpus1<-Corpus(VectorSource(as.vector(myCleanedText)))
myCorpus1<-tm_map(myCorpus1,content_transformer(tolower,removeURL,removeNumPunct),lazy=TRUE)
myCorpus1 <- tm_map(myCorpus1, removePunctuation,lazy=TRUE)
myCorpus1 <- tm_map(myCorpus1, removeNumbers,lazy=TRUE)
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), "available", "via")
myStopwords<-setdiff(myStopwords,c("afraid","fear")) #varsa stopwordden cikar
myCorpus1<-tm_map(myCorpus1, stripWhitespace,lazy=TRUE)
myCorpus1<-tm_map(myCorpus1,as.PlainTextDocument,mc.cores=1)
myDtm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus1, control = list(minWordLength = 1,weighting=weightTfIdf,minDocFreq=0)))

> myCorpus1
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 33704

> dim(myDtm)
[1] 10902  3732
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks ok. But without a specific data example where something is missing we can only guess what is going on. I suspect a lot of tweets are cleaned completely and have no words left in them. You might want to check some tweets after your cleaning process and see what is left of them.

Comment: How many documents are there if you remove the `minDocFreq` argument?